# 'ValuesViewHDF5' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried many solutions but can't seem to solve the problem. This code is in Python 2.7 and I am using Python 3.7. While searching I find out that this gives an error in Python 3.7. Can anyone help me how to remove this error in Python 3.7?

```
print('Loading c3d features ...')
        features = h5py.File(self._options['feature_data_path'], 'r') 
        self._feature_ids = features.keys()
        self._features = {video_id:np.asarray(features[video_id].values() 
        [0]) for video_id in self._feature_ids}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
E:\jupyter book\data_provider.py in <dictcomp>(.0)

    ---> 68         self._features 
             {video_id:np.asarray(features[video_id].values()[0]) for 
             video_id in self._feature_ids}
         69 
         70 

 TypeError: 'ValuesViewHDF5' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the subscript `[0]` outside the `np.asarray()` bit:

```
self._features = {video_id:np.asarray(features[video_id].values())[0] 
                 for video_id in self._feature_ids}
```

Or converting the `group.values()` object to a list:

```
self._features = {video_id:np.asarray(list(features[video_id].values())[0]) 
                  for video_id in self._feature_ids}
```

Calling `features[video_id].values()` with Py2 returns a list; on Py3, it returns a set-like object (http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html#Group.values). This means the `group.values()` object is no longer directly subscriptable in Py3. You'll need to convert it to a list or array-like object first via `list(group.values())` or `np.asarray(group.values())`. The same applies to `group.keys()` etc.